# Why is my post-commit Apache Subversion hook failing?

Tags: linux, email, svn

So I am trying to get a post-commit hook working on my Apache Subversion server, specifically I'm trying to send email to my Google account as described on [this link](http://iffee.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/svn-commit-to-google-apps-email-notification/).

After setting the permissions for the script and the working copy to the same user and read/write access it started causing MERGE errors when users tried to commit.

After some reading I found out that it was because of the post-commit hook not working and found out that by typing

```
svn - ./post-commit commit  ../ 250 mailer.conf
```

I get this error:

```
> annerajb@annerajb-desktop:~/Desktop/TotEM_SVN/hooks$ env - ./post-commit.test commit ../ 250

/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/svn/fs.py:27: DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.

  import sys as _sys, os as _os, popen2 as _popen2, tempfile as _tempfile

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py", line 1351, in <module>
    svn.core.run_app(main, cmd, config_fname, repos_dir, sys.argv[3:3+expected_args])

  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/svn/core.py", line 288, in run_app
    return apply(func, (application_pool,) + args, kw)

  File "/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py", line 80, in main
    revision = int(cmd_args[0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

./post-commit.test: 5: ../: Permission denied
```

I am not sure why cmd_args[0] is empty if I am passing it a value.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
/usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py commit "$REPOS" \
        "$REV" /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.conf
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your output to use fixed width fonts and include the contents of your post-commit file?

Comment: I dont know how to set the width of the fonts fonts. i will appreciate some instructions.

Comment: I made an attempt to cleanup the question a bit.  Please feel free to further edit or rollback if I destroyed your question at all!!!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it at all? Have you tried printing out the contents of cmd_args before that call to int(cmd_args[0])? eg. print cmd_args just to see what is there.

Answer (score 1):

permissions should not be set for working copy, but for repository access. Also execution right for the script should be set by user running svn server (or httpd server - depending on your solution).

From the error above looks like user running the script doesn't have direct repository access and cannot get revision number..

m